# How to redirect non-www to www with SSL for a specific domain not all parked domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have `test.yoursite.com` parked on `example.com` and have a SSL multi-domain certificate.

What I am asking is:

- when `http://example.com` requested, .htaccess should redirect it to `https://www.example.com`;
- when `http://test.yoursite.com` requested htaccess should redirect it to `https://test.yoursite.com`.

One of directions should work both with www and SSL redirection, another one is just for SSL redirection.

By the way I also have `example.net` parked on same host. I have tried several things which did not work. Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
# Dealing with a domain with/without www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%2.%3/$1 [L,R]

# Dealing with a domain that doesn't care about www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.%2.%3/$1 [L,R]
```

The first rule will redirect http://www.example.com/something to https://www.example.com/something as well as http://example.net/foo to https://www.example.net/foo

The second rule will redirect hosts that don't care about the "www", such as http://subdomain.domain.com/bar to https://subdomain.domain.com/bar

It will not, however, redirect http://sub-sub.subdomain.domain.com/.